# Uwsgi install error Centos7

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi

I'm trying to install on Centos7 the uwsgi so I can deploy a Python rest service on Centos7.
This is the guide that I have seen

[Instal Flask Restful Service On Centos](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7)

now I receive this error when I try to install uwsgi:

> Command "/home/admin60713620/Documents/PYTHON_REST_API/rest/restenv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oEZ7uf/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-vcgfSt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/admin60713620/Documents/PYTHON_REST_API/rest/restenv/include/site/python2.7/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oEZ7uf/uwsgi/

Comment: That last line only tells us the final exit code. The actual error should have been printed above that. Can you please include more output? You probably want to use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format it as code.

Comment: Try install `OS` required python modules (dev,essential, etc.)!

Comment: I have fix the error installing python-devel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and run this command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

If using python3

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev
```

and everything works!

Hope this help you!

Comment: I'm on Cento7 so i have done with "yum" because "apt-get" command not found, but i have always the same error

Comment: Oh! Didnt realize, im sorry! My bad!

Comment: Use yum as appgis said!